# Gönnen, reflexive or dativ

Tags: verb-usage

Can somebody explain to me, which of the following expressions is correct

- gönn dir
- gönn dich

Comment: Correctly it should read *gönne*. While it is often omitted (especially in commercials) , in writing at least an apostrophe should be used.,

Comment: @guidot Why? The imperative form doesn't require an *e*, and therefore no apostrophe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grammatically speaking: neither.
In contemporary colloquial language: 
»Gönn dir.«

The infinitive is »jemandem (oder: sich) etwas gönnen«, so »gönn dir« is just a shortened phrase, but it doesn't necessarily have an omitted part. Its meaning (but not its style) could be translated as »Indulge!«, »Enjoy!«, or »Go for it.«

> Ich will noch 'ne Runde zocken.
>   Gönn dir.

But also ironically:

> Ich muss noch zum Zahnarzt.
>   Gönn dir.

You mentioned »gönn dich«. This is wrong because it would be based on a verb structure that doesn't exist: »jemanden gönnen«.

Comment: I have never heard that.

Comment: @CarstenS Could be due to your age. It’s been around for a couple of years (5 to 10). Check out the entry on Mundmische: https://www.mundmische.de/bedeutung/35925-Goenn_dir. This just shows it existed 6 years ago, not, that it was actually used. But among my friends (25-35), it has become quite common recently, sort of as late adopters. I don’t know if the youth actually still uses it.

Comment: Interesting. Yes, could be my age, could also be regional.

Comment: I have never heard this peculiar usage, too. A viable form would be ***Gönn's dir***, which is short for *Gönne es dir*, meaning, approximately: "Feel free to enjoy it".

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann This is explicitly *not* »Gönn’s dir«, but the *es* has been omitted. The meaning is the same, though. This expression has absolutely hit the mainstream. Mediamarkt now has a »Gönn-dir-Dienstag« (https://www.mediamarkt.de/de/shop/goenn-dir-dienstag.html). If that’s not youth language commercialized, then I don’t know what would be, and they wouldn’t do that if there weren’t enough people who recognized the phrase.

Comment: @Philiipp it may well be youth slang, and salespeople make use of it; or it may be salespeople trying to insert idiotic-defective phrases into youth slang. Since, when large marketeers like those print something 5 million times in page-sized newspaper adds (and uncounted youtube ads) it may well become "mainstream" without having been used by real people beforehand.

Answer (score 2):

"gönne dir" is the right expression you missed an "e"

https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/goennen

It is Konjunktiv 1

https://www.dartmouth.edu/~deutsch/Grammatik/Subjunctive/KonjunktivI.html

Comment: Imperative is, without context, a more likely option. And your reference also lists the form without *e*.